# Bash script output htaccess file

Tags: linux, bash, .htaccess, unix

I would like to write a bash script that prints the content of a htaccess file. 
I tried that:

```
printf "File: \n"\
"`cat $PATH_TO_HTACCESS`\n"
```

But the output was something like:

```
"[some content of the htaccess file...]
line 2: printf: `{`: invalid format character"
```

So I think that the '{' character is not escaped.

I would like to send the output of this as an email like that:

```
| mail -s "Mail" xx@xx.xxx
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: `echo "File:"; cat "$PATH_TO_HTACCESS"`

Comment: I would like to send the output via email | mail -s "Mail" xxx@xx.xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should work on command line as well as on a shell script.

```
echo "File:";cat "$PATH_to_htaccess_file"
```

OR

```
cat script.ksh
echo "File:";cat "$PATH_to_htaccess_file"
```

Give script proper permissions and run it, it should provide the exact output needed by you then.

***EDIT:*** To send email with string `File` and Input_file do following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "File:"} 1'  Input_file | mailx -s"my email" singh_is_king@king.com
```

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to send the whole output via email?

Comment: @T.Meyer, please check my edit now and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Leading the e-mail with 'File:' looks quite spurious. Sending htacces by e-mail also looks very fishy - why would do it?

Either way, the feature you were looking for looks like this:

```
(echo File:; cat $PATH_TO_HTACCESS) | mail .....
```

Comment: I have a dynamic IP address and a script that is called every x minutes to look for an IP change. If thats the case, it updates some files and sends the updates via email.